# app runs much slower on VPN

Tags: vpn, firewall

I have an app that accesses the internal network at work.  I can run it from home via VPN but when I do, it runs much slower.  I suspect that it is getting timeouts caused by the firewall and somehow recovering.  Is there a utility I can run on my machine to diagnose this?  I'm thinking I can then request a modification to the firewall rules to relieve the timeouts.

Comment: At work, you're likely on a low-latency, high-bandwidth network. When at home, the traffic traverses a high-latency, low-bandwidth network. It shouldn't be surprising that things run slower over VPN.

Answer (score 4):

Running things via VPN is essentially slower due to the additional network hops and encryption.

If you must use a VPN, consider where the VPN is located (latency purposes) and the speed your getting from the connection.